# Hide application launcher icon but keeping application running

Tags: android, icons, hide, android-preferences, launcher

I added an option in my app settings to hide the app icon from launcher. It works, but if users return to another section (activity) of the app, app crashes.

Is there a way to prevent this, and keeping the app running until users leave it?

Thanks in advance. This is my code:

```
if (mPrefs.getLauncherIconShown()) {
    mPrefs.setIconShown(false);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to post a stack trace of the crash.

Comment: @Argyle app does not crash, actually. It simply closes. All the log says is `Process jahirfiquitiva.project (pid 22807) has died`